# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting based on empty cell with spaces

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting for a column: the background color should be green if the `Cell is empty`, otherwise the background color should be white. This works well except for spaces. So if there is a space (or more) in a cell, then the background color will be green - incorrectly.

Why? How can I avoid this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Custom Formula and if applied to a column, set the formula to:

```
=$B1<>""
```

I do not know why the logic for an empty cell is not the same is it may be for formulas such as ISBLANK() but it seems to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TRIM function to remove any white space in seemingly empty cells.

Check out (this link)[https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en] for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a formula in the cell, ISBLANK will return False.
You need to do a text compare and possibly a trim to evaluate the results of the formula.

ISBLANK default check

```
=ISBLANK(A1)
```

Cell has formula that evaluates to empty/blank

```
=(trim(A1)<>"")
```

Answer (score -1):

ISBLANK returns FALSE if the referenced cell has any content, including spaces, the empty string (""), and hidden characters. In case of unexpected FALSE results, try clearing the cell again to remove any hidden characters.